# ADF: Using look up and foreach activities to get and array ouput

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using `lookup` activity to scan my rows and `foreach` activity to concatinate my values into an array without any success.

The csv file that lookup is scanning looks like this:

```
value
a
b
c
d
```

my `foreach` looks like this :
[image]

and inside my `foreach` I have an `set variable` activity which I'm aware that the datatype is not matching but do not know how to solve

[image]

Comment: As your expected output is an array, you can direclty store the `@activiy('Lookup1').output.value` in an array variable using set variable activity without any Foreach.

Comment: 'foreach activity to concatinate my values into an array without any success.' - If you want to generate array inside ForEach, use append variable activity and give `@item().Table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because you are trying to pass an array value to a string type variable.

For your requirement you will have to use AppendVariable activity inside your ForEach and load all the iteration values to your AppendVariable of type array. Then outside of you ForEach, have setVariable activity of type array variable and map the AppendVariable to SetVariable

Below is sample pipeline JSON for the same requirement. You can reuse it by replacing the source dataset

```
{
"name": "pl_LookupToArray",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Lookup1",
            "type": "Lookup",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true,
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                },
                "dataset": {
                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText28",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                },
                "firstRowOnly": false
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach1",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Lookup1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Append variable1",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "appendVarArray",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@item().value",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Set variable2",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "ForEach1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "finalArrayValue",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@variables('appendVarArray')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "appendVarArray": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "finalArrayValue": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "annotations": []
}
```

}

Here is how the pipeline flow looks:

[image]

Here is how your final output value of your array type variable looks like :

```
{
"name": "finalArrayValue",
"value": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d"
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> concatinate my values into an array without any success.

Use **append variable** inside ForEach activity.

**My lookup activity:**

[image]

create an array variable. The second array variable is just for showing output.

[image]

**append variable:**

```
@item().value
```

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: do you connect `set variable` after `append variable` ? I get the following error message when i do it: **The variable 'res_show' of type 'Array' cannot be initialized or updated with value of type 'Object'. The variable 'res_show' only supports values of types 'Array'.**